# ASP.NET MVC App Windows Authentication stops working after using Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

This is bugging me, but think I traced the problem down to working on a Forms Authentication App and now I have switched back to trying to use Windows Authentication, but for some reason just wants to keep using Forms Authentication.

Have just the usual  in the web.config, even tried Signing Out of Forms Authentication, but still insists on working in Forms Authentication.

So the up-shot is I get when trying System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is a nice Empty string and user is not Authenticated.

How do I get my Windows Authentication back ?

cheers
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the web application folder is configured to use Windows authentication in IIS, also check the content files, they should inherit the parent permissions. Also re-check the authentication mode in your web.config file, make sure it's set to Windows.

Comment: Eeekk Sorry, should have specified..... this is debugging on my local machine, not deployed to IIS, just hitting the old debug and run button, my bad sorry about for not specifying that.

Comment: Are you using the VS internal crappy web engine or IIS Express? I would suggest maybe configuring your machine to use either IIS or IIS Express so that you get more of a feel of how it will behave on when you finally deploy it.

Comment: Yeah good point.... I will actually set it up in IIS, was just giving me the irks!

Comment: Wow...... still broken even when I have moved it to run under my local install of IIS.... Tries to redirect me to my login page because it reckons I am not authenticated.......

Comment: Just installed IIS Express and yeah that seems to work okay, can change from Annonymous to WIndows Authentication no worries.